# Convert 4 bytes to BigEndianStructure without converting to uint32 first

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I am converting date and time stored in 4 bytes to Python format. I came up with naive approach first. Then I tried to use `ctypes` so it should be faster:

```
from ctypes import *
from datetime import datetime


def bit_unpack(data, bits):
    value = int.from_bytes(data, "big")
    unpacked = []
    for i, field in enumerate(bits):
        shift = sum(bits[i+1:])
        mask = 2 ** field - 1
        bit_field = (value >> shift) & mask
        unpacked.append(bit_field)
    return unpacked


def to_date(data):
    y, m, d, h, n, s = bit_unpack(data, (6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6))
    return datetime(1980 + y, m, d, h, n, s)


class PackedDate(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("year", c_uint, 6),
        ("month", c_uint, 4),
        ("day", c_uint, 5),
        ("hours", c_uint, 5),
        ("minutes", c_uint, 6),
        ("seconds", c_uint, 6),
    ]


class Transfer(Union):
    _fields_ = [
        ("bytes", c_uint32),
        ("date", PackedDate),
    ]


def to_date2(data):
    transfer = Transfer()   
    transfer.bytes = int.from_bytes(data, "little")
    date = transfer.date
    return datetime(date.year + 1980, date.month, date.day, date.hours, date.minutes, date.seconds)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    byte_data = b'q\xa6\xb1\xdf'
    print(to_date(byte_data))
    print(to_date2(byte_data))

    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("to_date(byte_data)", r"from bitunpack import to_date; byte_data = b'q\xa6\xb1\xdf'"))
    print(timeit.timeit("to_date2(byte_data)", r"from bitunpack import to_date2; byte_data = b'q\xa6\xb1\xdf'"))
```

However, what I do not like is this part:

```
transfer.bytes = int.from_bytes(data, "little")
```

I am converting 4 bytes to uint32. Can I change my Union to be able to easier accept 4 bytes array without converting it to uint32 first? I tried `c_ubyte * 4` but got `TypeError: expected c_ubyte_Array_4 instance, got bytes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`from_buffer_copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._CData.from_buffer_copy) method that’s available on all `ctypes` types to create a `PackedDate` object directly from the `bytes` data:

```
>>> date = PackedDate.from_buffer_copy(data)
>>> datetime(date.year + 1980, date.month, date.day, date.hours, date.minutes, date.seconds)
datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 19, 11, 7, 31)
```

Comment: You are still calling `int.from_bytes(data, 'little')` to convert bytes to integer. I thought about avoiding this as I do not need the integer.

Comment: @Fenikso, use `date = PackedDate.from_buffer_copy(data)`.

Comment: @eryksun Wow, that’s a lot easier. I was hoping to find something like this but didn’t see it in the documentation. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @eryksun - That is what I was looking for. Please write it as an answer. I could not find it in the docs either...

Comment: @Fenikso You could have used [c_char_p](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p) directly (which converts from/to the `bytes` type) but that would have the wrong byte order.

Comment: @poke, for the `Union` approach you'd use `('bytes', c_char * 4)`, which lets you use `date = Transfer(data).date`. Using `c_char_p` would instead store the 4 byte (32-bit) or 8 byte (64-bit) address of the internal `char *` buffer of the `data` `bytes` object.

Comment: Or did you mean to `cast` `c_char_p(data)`? That's unnecessary since `cast` is implemented as a function pointer that automatically handles a `bytes` argument, e.g. `date = cast(data, POINTER(PackedDate))[0]`.

Comment: @eryksun I meant that, yeah. Awesome, I learned a lot about ctypes today. Thanks a lot! (You should still write an answer to this question btw.)

Comment: Since eryksun didn’t post an answer, I’ve edited mine to have the real solution. I’ve also made the answer community-wiki since it’s not mine.